# load dynamic content in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im using datatables, and this is my some of my code for fetching the data for datatables, this works fine now what i want is to load dynamic content on when someone hover or click the anchor tag... this the image [datatables data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogopf.jpg)

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="#" class="hover" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.clean($row["f_name"])." ".clean($row["m_name"])." ".clean($row["l_name"]).'</a>';
    $sub_array[] = strtoupper($row["sex"]);
    $sub_array[] = $row["birthdate"];
    $sub_array[] = $row['age'];
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
```

this is what i have tried, still the bootstrap popover not working

```
$('.hover').popover({
      title:fetchData,
      html:true,
      placement:'right'
    });

    function fetchData(){
      var fetch_data='';
      var element = $(this);
      var id = element.attr("id");

      $.ajax({
        url:"../controller/fetch_single.php",
        method:"POST",
        async:false,
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data){
          fetch_data = data;
          alert(data);
        }
      });
      return fetch_data;
    }
```

this is the code that i used for my ajax

```
//fetch_single.php
    if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {
        $output = '';
        $statement = $connection->prepare(
            "SELECT id, sex, f_name, m_name, l_name, birthdate,image_name,house_num,street TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE()) as age from rec_personal WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'"
            );
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $output = '
                <p><img src="../upload/'.$row["image_name"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" /></p>  
                <p><label>Name : '.$row['f_name'].'</label></p>  
                <p><label>Address : </label><br />'.$row['house_num'].'</p>  
                <p><label>Gender : </label>'.$row['sex'].'</p>  
                <p><label>Age : </label>'.$row['age'].' Years</p>  
                
            ';
        }
        echo $output;
    }
```

**EDIT**
this is my reference for the code http://www.webslesson.info/2016/11/php-ajax-jquery-load-dynamic-content-in-bootstrap-popover.html

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors when i clicked or hovered the anchor tag

Comment: there is no response on the ajax, no errors at all

Comment: Have you debugged?  What do you get returned on your success function?

Comment: no response on the ajax, and no errors on the console..

Comment: when i click the anchor tag the popover is not working

Comment: Try to add `data-toggle="popover"` to the <a> tag.

Comment: still not working :(